# How to write a unit test for a firebase callback trigger unit testing

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-unit-testing

I have the following test

group.service.spec.ts

```
import * as firebaseAdmin from "firebase-admin";
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions-test';
import { assert } from "chai";
import myFunctions from '../src/functions/createGroup';

const testEnv = functions();
const admin = firebaseAdmin.initializeApp();

describe("Group service", () => {
  let groupData;

  before(async () => {
    await admin.firestore().doc("groups/testGroup").set(groupData);
  });
  it("should create a group", async () => {
    // Mock data and context
    const data = {
      id: "testGroup",
      associationCode: null,
      courseId: "YmhWRhEAACMA1k-7",
      description: "Ok",
      meetingDates: "Tuesday, December 19",
      meetingFrequency: "2",
      meetingPlace: null,
      name: "Execution Time",
      virtualLink: null,
      appId: "itransform",
    };
    const context = { auth: { uid: "someNewParticipant" } };

    const myFunctions = require("../src/functions/createGroup");
    const snap = functionsTest.firestore.makeDocumentSnapshot(data, "groups/testGroup");
    const wrapped = functionsTest.wrap(myFunctions.createGroup);
    const result = await wrapped(data, context);

    assert.isDefined(result);
    const createdGroupSnap = await admin.firestore().doc("groups/testGroup").get();
    const createdGroup = createdGroupSnap.data();
    assert.deepEqual(createdGroup, data);
  });
});
```

createGroup.ts

```
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";

import { GroupService } from "../services";
import { admin } from "../firebaseApp";

export const createGroup = functions.runWith({
  timeoutSeconds: 120,
  memory: "1GB",
}).https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    // eslint-disable-next-line camelcase
    const userId = context.auth?.uid ?? context.auth?.token.user_id;

    const service = new GroupService(admin.firestore(), {
      userId,
      admin,
    });
    functions.logger.debug("handleCreateGroup", data);
    return await service.handleCreateGroup(data, context);
  } catch (e) {
    functions.logger.log("handleCreateGroup", e);
    throw e;
  }
});
```

I want to write a unit test to catch and create a group in typescript.